# Select only rows that satisfy 60% of the where clause - SQL Server

Tags: sql, ssms

I am facing a challenge in SQL. I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Books
WHERE
    Categories IN ('Fiction', 'art') OR
    Language IN ('en', 'de') OR
    Country = 'DE'
```

I need to look at the result if they are at least equal to two of these factors, it will be accepted, rather will not be selected.

E.g. if a book has `Category = Fiction` and `Language = FR` and  `Country = DE`

=> pass

A book with `Category = History` and `Language = FR` and `Country = DE`

=> failed

How can I achieve that in SQL?

I have tried to calculate a weight for each row. Each factor will add 0.3 to the complete weight and will pick only the one who has > 0.6

I also tried to group by. But I cannot really find the correct syntax.

Any ideas? Thanks!

P.S. I cannot put all the possibilities in my `where` clause because I have more than 3 factors.

Comment: `WHERE (CASE WHEN Categories IN ('Fiction', 'art') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE ...) >= 2` ?

Comment: Ooh, thanks! that solved the problem. I didn't know about the case syntax

Comment: Make sure you use the accepted answer as you should also use a WHERE clause to filter the rows, otherwise this will turn into a full tablescan.

Comment: I used actually both. Where is to minimize the effort and Select is to calculate the weight to order by. The performance is actually great. Thanks for the information. I changed the accepted answer to the one with where.

Comment: Actually the previously accepted answer was OK, I just wanted to point out that the CASE expression alone would result in a tablescan, you should also include the WHERE parts that filter on the properties as well, which the previously accepted answer did. The one you have accepted now lacks that filtering and will in fact do a tablescan (I assume).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from
(
    SELECT *,
           case when Categories in ('Fiction', 'art') then 1 else 0 end as cat_condition,
           case when Language in ('en', 'de') then 1 else 0 end as lang_condition,
           case when Country = 'DE' then 1 else 0 end as country_condition
    FROM Books
    WHERE
        Categories in ('Fiction', 'art') OR
        Language in ('en', 'de') OR
        Country = 'DE'
) tmp
where cat_condition + lang_condition + country_condition >= 2
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one situation where a `case` expression in the `where` clause is sensible:

```
SELECT *
FROM Books
WHERE ( (CASE WHEN Categories in ('Fiction', 'art') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN Language IN ('en', 'de') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN Country = 'DE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      ) >= 2;
```

Or, alternatively:

```
WHERE ( (CASE WHEN Categories in ('Fiction', 'art') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN Language IN ('en', 'de') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN Country = 'DE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      ) / 3.0 >= 0.6
```